# Functional programming in Java 7

Tags: java, functional-programming

Does Java 7 have functional programming support or I still need to use FunctionalJava or another lib? I thought is has support to this, but didn't find much info about it.

Comment: You can read about the current state of [Project Lambda](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/) at OpenJDK.

Comment: Even once Java adds Lambdas, I still don't think it will be a good fit. Try as you might, Java's imperative nature will continually interfere. You can still derive benefits from the attempt though. Like better state management, but there are other languages in the JVM that it just works better.

Comment: Hopefully not. Dont mix up oo with func.

Comment: @AlexWien Why not? Scala and F# successfully do this. Not to mention, C#'s lambdas are really, really good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would depend on your definition of Functional Programming.

In any case, the answer to your question would be No. Lambdas were due to appear in Java7 at one point but they will appear only in Java8. It *looks* like with Java8 you'll be able to [do a lot with the new lambda notation in conjunction with the regular JDK8 class libraries](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/collections-overview.html)  (collections in particular) before you need something like FunctionalJava, but that sort of depends on how much you want to do. A lot of OO folk will be very happy with just a flavor of FP - a common example is collections with `map`, `filter` etc. That by itself would no doubt move Java *closer* to FP - and might just be FP enough for you.

The question is, even then, would that allow true (even if 'impure') functional programming in Java? Yes, and No. *Yes*, because any language with lexical closures and a lambda notation could in theory be enough.  *No*, because FP as supported by languages `Haskell`, `F#`, `OCAML` and `Scala` would still be impractical.

Some examples:

1. The lack of [Algebraic Data Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) - these are regarded as a key component of the 
   statically typed family of FP languages, and go especially well with many FP idioms.
2. While not exactly a requirement for FP, nearly all statically typed FP languages feature
   some form of *type inference*.
3. Statements need to behave like expressions for a lot of Functional Programming
   idioms to be convenient - `if`, `try`, etc need to *return a value*.
4. Enforcement (as in Haskell),  or the encouraging (as in Scala) of 
   *single assignment* as well as *immutability*, and a useful collection 
   of data structures and libraries to that end.

Other languages like Lisp/Scheme or Erlang are also considered Functional; but in a less strict sense; the requirements (1), and (2) do not apply because they are *dynamically typed* to begin with.

One can say then, that Javascript is about as functional as Lisp (impure dynamic functional language), because Javascript has always had lambdas and first-class functions. But Java being in the *statically* typed family, does not fare any better (than Javascript) and certainly not as well as the existing statically typed FP languages.

Regarding (4. (Immutable/Side-effect free)), it appears that in JDK8, the existing mutable classes will be *retrofitted* with lambda-consuming methods, so that's something that will (at least for a while) limit how far you can take FP paradigms in Java8.

I found these links very useful - I haven't been following up for a while though, so I'm not sure if they are the best/latest info regarding this. But worth reading:

http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html

http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/collections-overview.html

Comment: java features a form of type inference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: Good point. But the savings in verbosity are still very minor, compared to both local type inference (Scala) or full-blown Hindley-Milner type inference (Haskell, ML). While Java's type inference helps when dealing with generic methods and instantiations of generic classes, FP-style type inference lets you have local variables sans explicit declarations and yet have them statically checked. I'd say the difference is huge, in that it significantly contributes to succinctness.

Comment: Indeed, the difference is very big! Just wanted to point out that Java also has some kind of type inference although it's not comparable to the one of 'proper' functional languages